# Instantiate a Java object through reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have a question regarding a specific way of instantiating a Java object.

Basically, I need to implement a Singleton which implements an interface. I currently try to use a factory and a bit of reflection to do this, trying to reproduce [this example](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t134995-singleton-through-an-interface.html) (5th post, precisely).

The part that I like is that through this method, I can change the Singleton's implementation quite easily.

The problem is that I don't really understand how to retrieve the Class name. In the example above, the `System.getProperty()` seems to be a way to do this, but the example doesn't show precisely all the types needed to do this (the field isn't typed). The problem is that I don't know which key to give to the `getProperty()` method. It seems that it must be the singleton private static field's name with .type (i.e. `mySingleton.name`), but it doesn't seem to work...

I would like to know how can I retrieve the class name.

By the way, if there's a better way to do this, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I suggest you have a good look at `java.util.ServiceLoader` before you go too far down this path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typeName is String . So what you need is Fully Qualified Class Name to load the class with reflection like you

> Class type = Class.forName(typeName);

System.getProperty() is a way to access the system properties/ environment properties that you have at the time of executing the program. 
To narrow it down for you with an example you can set the system varible like below :
If in windows :

> cmd> set a.type = mytest.testclass

If in linux :

> $ export a.type = mytest.testclass

Make your the class that you are try to load is in classpath.

The above steps you need to perform before running your program.

Coming to best practices, the above approach can be used to test programs but when going into real time solutions you probably will have some way to read these class name from a file or database. Probably some kind of configuration parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about `String typeName = System.getProperty("a.type");` in"

```
private synchronized static final void createA()
{
    // This is just one possibility for getting the class name.
    String typeName = System.getProperty("a.type");
    Class type = Class.forName(typeName);
    a = type.newInstance();
}
```

Where does `a.type` come from? - it's just System property, declared in your Operating system for this purpose only.

```
Class c = Class.forName("java.lang.String");
```

as shown above - `Class.forName()` requires fully qualified name of class - with package declaration

Comment: That's precisely what I was wondering. I don't know where it comes, whether it's generated by Java for each objects in the properties, or defined by setting manually this property.

Comment: is set maunaly, treating Windows/Linux/whatever as property file.

Comment: @user1594913 If its not a built in property it is set whatever you set it to e.g. with `-Dproperty=value` on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the property anything you want. You can get the properties with `System.getProperty("my.property")` and you can turn this into a class with `Class.forName()`

Perhaps you could say what didn't work for you as its all pretty simple and I assume you are doing almost the right thing.

Comment: Well it seems the property wasn't found. I thought it was a generated property (like say, for every class, a set of properties is defined), whereas in fact it's not and then it couldn't find it. I may have to define manually the name of the class I want to instanciate then...

Comment: There is no way for the JVM to know which property to define or what class name to set it to. What you can do is provided a default e.g. `System.getProperty("my.property", "my.package.class")` so you always get a class whether it is set or not.